# Keep getting error in postman as below ? Could not get any response

Tags: laravel, api, postman, lumen

[image]

This is from the postman console for the error. Could anyone help with it ?

Comment: `Error: read ECONNRESET` means your application dropped it's TCP connection. Check your application log.You tag it as `laravel` and `lumen` but it looks like you use nodejs. The default Laravel dev server port is 8000, but yours is 3306. Are you using Laravel or nodejs?

Comment: It's lumen for api. The default post is 3306 as Xampp. Error: read ECONNRESET is gone now because I was connection VPN just now. Now the error showing 

Error: Parse Error

Comment: So it was problem with your connection. Check if you have any firewall active. Parse error means there's a problem with your script when parsing something.